# RMI Instantiate Remote Objects

Tags: java, rmi

I have an RMI server export a single "Manager" class. The RMI client connects to the server, and retrieves the instance of the "Manager" class. Then, I call "Manager.createBox()", which creates a box, and then "Manager.getBox(0)" to retrieve the box.

Now, if I make any changes to that "Box" that I just retrieved, modify it, and then call "Manager.getBox(0)" again, I get the original box again without my changes.. How can I "commit" the changes I just made to Box on the client side? Or, do I need to add a method to the manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Box ia a simple serializable class, then its state is simply serialized, sent on the wire, and deserialized on the client when getBox is called. The client thus modifies a copy of the box, and not the original one.

If you want the modified box to be on the server, then either send it back to the server (`manager.modifyBox(box)`), or make the Box a remote object (by making it a remote interface Box, implemented by a BoxImpl concrete class extending UnicastRemoteObject).